# Building and updating a sparse matrix in python using scipy

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to build and update a sparse matrix as I read data from file.
The matrix is of size `100000X40000`

What is the most efficient way of updating multiple entries of the sparse matrix?
specifically I need to increment each entry by 1.

Let's say I have row indices `[2, 236, 246, 389, 1691]`

and column indices `[117, 3, 34, 2757, 74, 1635, 52]`

so all the following entries must be incremented by one:

`(2,117) (2,3) (2,34) (2,2757) ...`

`(236,117) (236,3) (236, 34) (236,2757) ...`

and so on.

I'm already using `lil_matrix` as it gave me a warning to use while I tried to update a single entry.

`lil_matrix` format is already not supporting multiple updating.
`matrix[1:3,0] += [2,3]` is giving me a notimplemented error.

I can do this naively, by incrementing every entry individually. I was wondering if there is any better way to do this, or better sparse matrix implementation that I can use.

My computer is also an average i5 machine with 4GB RAM, so I have to be careful not to blow it up :)

Comment: it works for `lil_matrix` if the right hand side is `numpy` array of matching shape, like `A[1:3, 0] += np.array( [[ 2 ],[ 3 ]] )`

Comment: yeah i figured that part out. but do you have any suggestions for my specific problem? like given the row indices and column indices, i want to increment all the combination entries as given in the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Creating a second matrix with `1`s in your new coordinates and adding it to the existing one is a possible way of doing this:

```
>>> import scipy.sparse as sps
>>> shape = (1000, 2000)
>>> rows, cols = 1000, 2000
>>> sps_acc = sps.coo_matrix((rows, cols)) # empty matrix
>>> for j in xrange(100): # add 100 sets of 100 1's
...     r = np.random.randint(rows, size=100)
...     c = np.random.randint(cols, size=100)
...     d = np.ones((100,))
...     sps_acc = sps_acc + sps.coo_matrix((d, (r, c)), shape=(rows, cols))
... 
>>> sps_acc
<1000x2000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 9985 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import scipy.sparse

rows = [2, 236, 246, 389, 1691]
cols = [117, 3, 34, 2757, 74, 1635, 52]
prod = [(x, y) for x in rows for y in cols] # combinations
r = [x for (x, y) in prod] # x_coordinate
c = [y for (x, y) in prod] # y_coordinate
data = [1] * len(r)
m = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data, (r, c)), shape=(100000, 40000))
```

I think it works well and doesn't need loops. I am directly following the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix)

```
<100000x40000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 35 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Comment: cols_iter = cycle(cols), r,c = zip(*[(x, cols_iter.next()) for x in rows ]) and data = np.ones(len(r)) makes this slightly faster

Comment: is this efficient way of doing it? I mean can I add this to my main matrix in every iteration, every iteration i get a new row and column arrays.

Comment: @syllogismos I think so, by the doc, it is how the new sparse matrix is generated. Should be at least faster than looping.

Comment: m is the resultant matrix in every iteration, and f is my main matrix which is also in coo_matrix. 

can i just do, f += m?

and what format should f and m be. its given in the documentation that coo_matrix not very efficient for arithmetic operations.

Comment: @syllogismos As I notice, the `m` is directly generated by the data values in specific indices, so it doesn't involve much arithmetic operations.

Comment: the thing is I get a new rows, cols arrays for every iteration from the outer loop. So I have a new m for every iteration.. and I need to add m to my main sparse matrix if I do things according to your answer.

Comment: the first answer does exactly that, make a temporary sparse matrix of size 100000X40000 on every iteration and adds it to my main matrix. I will try doing this and check if I get any problems.. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This answer expands the comment of @behzad.nouri.  To increment the values at the "outer product" of your lists of rows and columns indices, just create these as numpy arrays configured for broadcasting.  In this case, that means put the rows into a column.  For example,

```
In [59]: a = lil_matrix((4,4), dtype=int)

In [60]: a.A
Out[60]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [61]: rows = np.array([1,3]).reshape(-1, 1)

In [62]: rows
Out[62]: 
array([[1],
       [3]])

In [63]: cols = np.array([0, 2, 3])

In [64]: a[rows, cols] += np.ones((rows.size, cols.size))

In [65]: a.A
Out[65]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])

In [66]: rows = np.array([0, 1]).reshape(-1,1)

In [67]: cols = np.array([1, 2])

In [68]: a[rows, cols] += np.ones((rows.size, cols.size))

In [69]: a.A
Out[69]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: I'm happy with this solution since it allows you to update one row at a time in the sparse lil_matrix.