# How to manually create a sparse matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a text file containing data representing a sparse matrix with the following format:

```
0 234 345
0 236 
0 345 365 465
0 12 35 379
```

The data is used for a classification task and each row can be considered a feature vector. The first value in each row represents a label, the values following it represent the presence of individual features.

I'm trying to create a sparse matrix with these values (to use in a machine learning task with scikit learn). I've found and read the [scipy.sparse documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html) but I'm failing to understand how to incrementally build up a sparse matrix with source data like this.

The examples I've found so far show how to take a dense matrix and convert it, or how to create a native sparse matrix with contrived data, but no examples that have helped me here. I did find this related SO question ([Building and updating a sparse matrix in python using scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583381/building-and-updating-a-sparse-matrix-in-python-using-scipy)), but the example assumes you know the max COL, ROW sizes, which I don't, so that data type doesn't seem appropriate.

So far I have the following code to read the document and parse the values into something that seems reasonable:

```
def get_sparse_matrix():
    matrix = []
    with open("data.dat", 'r') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            row = line.strip().split()
            label = row[0]
            features = entry[1:]
            matrix.append([(i, col) for col in features])

    sparse_matrix = #magic happens here

    return sparse_matrix
```

So questions are,

- What is the appropriate sparse matrix type to use here?
- Am I heading in the right direction with the code I have?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the format, for every element in the matrix, you need `row,` `col, and `value`. Where is the `value` information? To create the sparse matrix incrementally, you can use: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.dok_matrix

Comment: If it needs to have a value, then it could be 1 or True. Does that clarify it?

Comment: @HYRY hanks for the tip on dok_matrix, but don't I still need to know the total number of columns when I initialize the dok_matrix? Part of my problem is that I don't reliably know what the max COL value will be. I could write a script that finds out the max value for a given data file, but thought there might be some existing scipy sparse matrix datatype that doesn't require me to specify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `coo_matrix()`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
data = """0 234 345
0 236 
0 345 365 465
0 12 35 379"""

column_list = []
for line in data.split("\n"):
    values = [int(x) for x in line.strip().split()[1:]]
    column_list.append(values)
lengths = [len(row) for row in column_list]
cols = np.concatenate(column_list)
rows = np.repeat(np.arange(len(column_list)), lengths)
m = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones_like(rows), (rows, cols)))
```

Here is the code to check the result:

```
np.where(m.toarray())
```

the output:

```
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]),
 array([234, 345, 236, 345, 365, 465,  12,  35, 379]))
```